# Getting the current user in sifefinity 4.4

Tags: sitefinity-4

How do I pro-grammatically get the current user that is logged into sitefinity 4.4?

Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are in the context of a Sitefinity page, you can do this:

```
var uId = Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.SecurityManager.GetCurrentUserId();
```

It's just a static method on the SecurityManager class.